# introducing exception handling

Tags: java, exception

Can I use exception handling in the following examples?

```
 public setTime(int hour, int minute, int second){
  this.hour = hour;
  this.minute= minute;
  this second = second;
```

and

```
public static final MIN_REFRESH_RATE = 1;
public static final MAX_REFRESH_RATE = 100;

public void setRefreshRate(int rate){
setRefreshInreval(int rate);
}
```

Comment: Can you? Yes. What more would you like to know?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I need to use exception handling for this 2 examples and I don't find any purpose to do this in this code. Can be try{ this.hours= hours;....} catch (...){}  and static{ try { setRefreshInreval(int rate);} catch(){} ?

Comment: where are you getting input?

Comment: In the first case, there won't be any exceptions that you'll need to _catch_, but you might want to **throw** some.  Like `if (minute < 0 || minute >= 60) throw new IllegalArgumentException("minute out of range");`

Comment: @KevinAnderson as second option,  could I use assert(minute<0 ||minute >=60) etc? For the second example is fine if i use startic{try{....?

Comment: Here you'd want to throw an exception, because it's reasonable for whoever calls you routine to want to catch that exception and try to handle it somehow (like maybe by asking the user to enter a correct time).  Assertions are meant for problems that the caller of your routine can't do anything about.

Comment: @JavaRookie I only need to show how exceptions and/or assert works...it is free to chose whatever i want

Comment: @KevinAnderson thanks a lot! any idea how I could calculate CBO? ...for this uml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364867/calculate-coupling-between-objects

Comment: @ Vasilescu Catalin then you better try exception handling in the place where you get values for the variables